# UIWebview Logout

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, background

Can anyone tell me how to logout UIWebview when Application entered Background?

I need to call a js function such as offline() through UIWebview.

when i call this function with 
[mywebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"offline()"];
this method is not working.
but this is working when application  entered foreground back.

how could I get it work?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the javascript does not execute in time before the app goes into the background. You can request more time by running a backgroundTask in you appdelegate's applicationWillResignActive method:

```
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{                        
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    });
}];
```

Also make sure to end the background task once you know your javascript it complete (because its javascript within a webview, the only way might just be to call it after N number of seconds):

```
// After N sections execute this:
if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```